# LinkedIn summaries in different languages

Tags: linkedin

I finished my studies last summer, and have been working since January 2016, so I have a rather short LinkedIn profile. To keep it short, the study-related project summaries I have are written in Spanish but everything else is in English.

I was wondering if this could be considered unprofessional by people reading my profile. **What downsides are there to having different sections in different languages? Should I restrict my profile to a single language?**

Comment: I've edited your question to focus on the core question and trim it for length. Your question on whether the profile should be in English or the local language should be posted in a separate question if there's no other question about that already (check first).

Comment: Minor note: ensure that you have your profile proofread by someone who has extensive experience with English, preferably a native speaker. At the very least you need to run it through a spell check *and* double-check all the idioms you use. Your use of backfire was incorrect for instance and you had several typos and spelling errors in this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on who your intended audience is.

If you attempting to sell your self ( which is the main purpose of linked in besides the networking aspect ) to mainly English speaking companies, I would go with all English.  If you attempting to sell yourself to Spanish speaking companies, I would go with Spanish.

If you seek opportunities in both environments ( SP and ENG ), I would suggest all English and make certain its clear you are bi-lingual.

I would not have your linked in profile built with two different languages.

Comment: That makes sense. I finally opted to go with all in spanish, and maybe in the future I'll change it to english. Thanks for the answer!